# What is the equivalent of "make sense" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, word-requests

I am trying to explain the phrase "make sense" to my cousin, who is learning English. The dictionary suggests "有意义", but I believe that "有意义" is "meaningful" and that "make sense" should be "讲得通", "说得通", or "符合逻辑".

Consider the following situation:

> 我一个北京的朋友居然在上中文入门这门课！
>
> One of my friends from Beijing is taking Chinese 101! [It doesn't make
>   any sense!]

How do I translate the part in brackets? “这根本说不通？” Or maybe "居然" alone suffices?

[Here is another example on Tatoeba.org.](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/637385) Is "你说的没有意义" "what you said is insignificant"? Since "有意义" is used pretty often in Chinese, I am wondering whether there *is* an English equivalent.

Comment: +1 有意义 is a common understanding。But 有意义 doesn't mean meaningful only, it depends on context.

Answer (score 16):

The most appropriate translation to `make sense` would probably be `有道理`, which literally means `has sense or reason`.  For example:

```
你说的有道理
What you said is reasonable / What you said makes sense.
```

The phrase `说不通` would probably work, but it is not used frequently in Mainland China Mandarin (普通话) as `有道理` for the same context, if at all.

As for `符合逻辑`, the phrase means the same thing as `有道理`, but it is more verbose and academic.  It is like saying:

```
That is well reasoned. 
---as opposed to---
That makes sense.
```

As you can see the latter is what people use in daily conversations, while the former make you sound like some College Professor. ;-)

`[It doesn't make any sense]` would translate to `这没有道理`。  Though in the context of your example, I think it sounds more natural in the Chinese context to say `It is ridiculous (这太荒唐了）` in response to the situation. Cultural differences in the way we think I suppose.

Comment: 有道理 = "make sense" is a perfect translation (and it happens to be literal!). But when it comes to "doesn't make sense"- for example, does “我的一个北京朋友居然在大学上中文入门！【这根本没道理！】” sound right to you? Also, are you from northern China? I'm a native speaker from the south and "说不通" isn't archaic or rare here at all.

Comment: @gonnastop I updated my answer to your question.  Yes the translation sounds natural enough as to not be weird.  Though I think it is more natural to react to a ridiculous situation in the Chinese context with an affirmative, even though in English either way works fine.  And yes I am a native speaker from the North, so "说不通" is not a commonly used phrase for me.

Comment: quite common phrases 「不是吧」「不可能吧」「搞笑吧你」

Comment: "make sense" in English has two meanings.  One is something that is not silly/illogical; the other is meaningful/having meaning, e.g., "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously" "Huh?  That makes no sense."

Answer (score 5):

英译汉时，一个很重要的问题，就是英汉词汇适用的范围常常是不同的。make sense 和 doesn't make sense这两个英文词（组）在英文中的适用范围是很宽泛的，但翻译成中文时，就得根据上下文及语境仔细斟酌了。

When translating from English to Chinese, a very important problem is that the usage range of English and Chinese vocabulary is often not the same. The usage range of the two English phrases `make sense` and `doesn't make sense` in English is very wide-ranging, but when translating into Chinese, one has to carefully consider what's written above and below, and the context.

One of my friends from Beijing is taking Chinese 101! [It doesn't make any sense!]

可以译成 (can be translated as)：我一个北京来的朋友居然在上中文入门课！[真是胡闹！][真荒唐！][真有病！]

Note: If anyone has a better suggestion on how to differentiate `上下文` and `语境`, please suggest. I'll be happy to hear from you.

Answer (score 4):

In Taiwan, I frequently hear all three of

沒有道理

說不通

沒有意思

Personally, I usually use 沒有意思. I think this is one of those situations where the literally meaning doesn't quite capture the sentiment (which is, indeed, "doesn't make sense") while the literal meaning misses the point.

Edit: If I were reacting to an absurd statement ("That doesn't make sense") I would probably say 怎麼意思？ However, if I were describing a situation, then I would probably lean towards 說不通. I think it's true that it probably differs by region though.

Answer (score 1):

```
我一个北京的朋友居然在上中文入门这门课！
One of my friends from Beijing is taking Chinese 101! [It doesn't make any sense!]
```

If `It doesn't make any sense!` means that you think he's crazy, then you could say `有病!`.

If `It doesn't make any sense!` means that you are puzzled by his intentions, then you could say `真耐人尋味`.

If `It doesn't make any sense!` literally means that you cannot understand why he's doing it, then you could say `真的叫我無法了解`.

Answer (score 1):

The best translation depends on the specific language context because 'make sense' has broader meaning than its Chinese counterparts: 有道理，说得通，靠谱……

For this particular example in your question:

One of my friends from Beijing is taking Chinese 101! [It doesn't make any sense!]

我一个北京的朋友居然在上中文入门这门课！[***开什么玩笑啊！***]

Answer (score -2):

> One of my friends from Beijing is taking Chinese 101! [It doesn't make any sense!]

[It doesn't make any sense!]

这根本不可能。/这是不可能的事。

Comment: 可能 is more like possible. Your answer provided translates more to: 'This can't be possible. / This (thing) is not possible.'